# Python. Conans module for conanfile.py

Tags: python, conan

I often see a lot of `conanfile.py` and all of them have something like that  `from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools` but I cannot find `conans` module in python registry. Where I can find some helper or like that to write my config files in type-safe way with autocompletion?

Comment: having the same issue. were you able to solve it?

Comment: @ArsenZahray, no, seems like conan doesn't provide a strict API for recipes and rely on some kind of reflection or indirect usage of the API. Didn't check conan v.2, maybe there they implemented this

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have Conan installed in your environment, to have all python files available for reading.

So you need to configure your IDE or code editor to find your python files based in your Python interpreter. Most of IDEs are able to deduce it automatically (PyCharm, vscode, vim...), so it's not a Conan feature.

Here is an example for Atom: [Adding modules in atom in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455945/adding-modules-in-atom-in-python)