# matplotlib installed - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I installed matplotlib.

But when i try to import it into my project 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

it say
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

pip list gives me:
matplotlib         3.2.1

I am using Atom

I tried reinstalling matplotlib several times and every solution i could find on google, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check if the python versions of `pip` and the one you're using to run the code match. Also check out the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455945/adding-modules-in-atom-in-python

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can make your code not to find the module, one of the common problem is having multiple python versions installed on your computer. Using a virtual environment to manage the project will help fix such problems on your project.

- On your project directory, create a virtual environment with venv
  `python3 -m venv workspace`
  workspace is the name of the environment, you can give it any name you want
- Activate the virtual environment
  On PC use this code
  `workspace\Scripts\activate.bat`
  On Mac/Linux
  `source venv/bin/activate`
- Install matplotlib in the virtual environment and run your code

**When you are done you could deactivate the environment with this code**
`deactivate`